# The device you inserted does not contain Chrome OS

Tags: boot, google-chrome, usb

The system is an HP Chromebook 11 G5 N3060 laptop.

I've flashed a USB flash drive with Linux Mint on it, first using the ChromeOS recovery tool, and secondly with etcher on an Apple computer.

I've successfully enabled developer mode, turned off OS verification, etc., but when I try to boot from the USB flash drive, it just says:

> "The device you inserted does not contain Chrome OS."

I've tried multiple times to get this to work, but the same message keeps popping up. What is going on? Do Chromebooks just...not allow booting an OS that's not Chrome? Why won't this work?

I don't understand, because I've read so many articles saying that this is perfectly acceptable, yet I seem to find that this Chromebook just refuses to boot anything from a USB flash drive that's not ChromeOS.

Comment: I've never done it but it looks like you'll have to install a different firmware on your device. There's extensive documentation on https://mrchromebox.tech/

Comment: [HP Chromebook 11 G5 config recommendation](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/7kgizt/hp_chromebook_11_g5_config_recommendation/) says: "you have to install the RW_LEGACY firmware update via my [Firmware Utility Script](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript) because Braswell-based ChromeOS devices do not include Legacy Boot firmware in the stock firmware image (the RW_LEGACY firmware slot/region is blank)."  I have also seen GalliumOS recommended for this device. [Useful reference](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+to+convert+a+generic+Chromebook+to+Linux+OS/108259).

Comment: Listen to @harrymc. As to WHAT is braswell: that is the codename intel gave the CPU/processor in this PC. [Specs page for that PC](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05182225#AbT1) indicate its a [Celeron N3060 which on the intel website](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/91832/intel-celeron-processor-n3060-2m-cache-up-to-2-48-ghz.html) mentions braswell. At the link from harrymc it also mentions 'Braswell-based ChromeOS devices aren't well-supported in the mainline Linux kernel / in most distros' & your model even has an issue with the recommend distro GalliumOS

Answer (score 1):

The Redit post
[HP Chromebook 11 G5 config recommendation](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/7kgizt/hp_chromebook_11_g5_config_recommendation/)
has an excellent answer by a user named MrChromebox,
that has these useful remarks:

> It bears mentioning that Braswell-based ChromeOS devices aren't
> well-supported in the mainline Linux kernel / in most distros, so
> you'll want to stick with one that actually supports ChromeOS hardware
> (like GalliumOS) unless you're wanting to build your own patched
> kernel etc.
>
> One additional note is that some Braswell-based devices have issues
> with the latest ChromeOS firmware, and your device is one of them. See
> the GalliumOS issue tracker entry for more info:
> https://github.com/GalliumOS/galliumos-distro/issues/320

I note the above GalliumOS issue dates from 2017, that its priority
is marked as High, but that nothing feasible was ever fixed.

If you wish to try and install GalliumOS, the user had some advice:

> you have to install the RW_LEGACY firmware update via my [Firmware
> Utility Script](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript) because
> Braswell-based ChromeOS devices do not include Legacy Boot firmware in
> the stock firmware image (the RW_LEGACY firmware slot/region is
> blank).

And also:

> if your device has support for Android Apps via the play store, you might not want to give that up, so dual booting might be better in that case.